# On a little-endian machine, how will bit operators work?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, endianness

I have the following code that takes pixel values from a file. I am on a Intel macbook running OS X. I believe that is little-endian. I have the following code which I am using to determine if the least significant bit is set on the pixels. It compiles and runs, but I am not sure if by operations are really giving me the correct data.

```
 typedef struct {
    unsigned char blue;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char red;
 } pixel_t;

 pixel_t *pixels = malloc(((bmp->dib.bmp_bytesz/3)+1) * sizeof(*pixels));

 printf("%u", (pixels[i].red & 0x01));
 printf("%u", (pixels[i].green & 0x01));
 printf("%u", (pixels[i].blue & 0x01));
```

Comment: Before asking a question about endian-ness, you should know what it is. It is not at all relevant to your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Little-endian and big-endian refers to the order of bytes (not bits, per se) in larger units (like `short` or `int`).

The bitwise operations are the same; the operations are giving you the least significant bit of the numbers in `pixels[i].blue` etc.  If they are stored in `char` (or `unsigned char` or `signed char`), then there is no issue.  If they are stored in `int` or `short` or something, then the byte that is being addressed will be different depending on whether the machine is big-endian or little-endian, but it is still the least significant bit of the number on the platform.

Comment: I had one question though. If you wrote out a struct{} to a file on a Little endian machine and read the file back into a struct on a Big endian machine, who would be responsible for resolving the endian differences?

Comment: The programmer.  You can define which programmer.  Some systems use 'sender makes right'; some systems use 'receiver makes right'; some systems have other rules.  For network control data (IP addresses etc), the data is transferred in a machine-neutral order (that happens to be big-endian, IIRC) and those machines that are not using the machine-neutral order have to fix things up.

Comment: @user1930928 Since your struct only contains chars, endianness isn't relevant.

Comment: @JimBalter: Actually, it was 'effervescent-phantom' who asked the question; user1930928 asked the subsidiary — so the structures under discussion may not be 'all char'.

Answer (score 5):

Endianess is an internal detail affecting how values are *stored*. It has no effect on how values are *computed*.

Answer (score 2):

Jonathan has the right answer already...just adding an example.

Endianness describes how multi-byte data is stored in computer memory. It describes the location of the most significant byte (MSB) and least significant byte (LSB) of an address in memory. 
Big Endian: Stores MSB first i.e. left to right
Little Endian: Stores LSB first i.e. right to left.

Example: How is 0x04030201 stored in memory?

```
Address     BE  LE
00000000    04  01
00000001    03  02
00000002    02  03
00000003    01  04
```